# Finding a function to map from logical to physical addresses

Tags: algebra-precalculus, computer-science

This is sort of an unusual question. For you to understand, you'll need to look at the picture below. The gray background is irrelevant.

[image]

You can notice there are $4$ discs, splitted to numbered **logical** sectors. What I wish to find is the **physical** address of a sector (the position within the disc itself).

For example,

- The sector numbered $13$ is actually located at the physical address number $05$.
- The sector numbered $06$ is actually located at the physical address number $02$.

Terminology:

- A *Block* is a row of sectors ($4$ in our case)
- A *strip* is a row of blocks (also $4$ in our case)

Basically, we can reduce our problem only for the first $4$ rows since the same can be applied for the others.

I'd be glad to get help with figuring out a formula (or a pseudo-code) which converts logical to physical addresses.

**UPDATE**
Barry kindly helped me with converting a logical to physical address (it actually very inventive when I think about it).

I also need to to return the device number ($0-3$).
How do I do that?

Comment: Do you want a short, "tricky", or one that is longer but more easily modifiable? Can the pseudo-code have conditional statements? Can constant arrays be used? Why not just use a constant array of $96$ elements for a simple one-step lookup?

Comment: $4 \left\lfloor \frac{x}{12}\right\rfloor +(x \bmod 4)$ would be my first guess.

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I doesn't have to be tricky and yes, constant arrays can be used

Comment: @barrycarter, many thanks (I understood the meaning of the formula).
could you also help me figure out the device_number? (0-3)

Comment: $\frac{(\text{logical_address} \mod  12)}{ 4}$ works only for the addresses "above" the diagonal

Comment: @barrycarter, any chance you got a solution for that?